# DNS servers not set properly? Site failing to load by hostname, though loads fine by IP

Tags: dns, dns-servers, dynamic-dns

We run `www.tekiki.com`. Some users, including us, cannot reach `www.tekiki.com` because of DNS issues. The site resolves fine on the desktop, but it fails from our iPhones and iPads. This doesn't happen to everyone. We noticed the problem yesterday, then set our DNS servers to Cloudflare's DNS servers, hoping that would fix things.

Accessing the site by IP addr loads the site fine.

Two questions:

1) Does anyone know what the solution is?

2) Should we use other DNS servers besides Cloudflare?

Comment: Get a report on your DNS, http://www.dnsstuff.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your site appears to be loading fine now. It's possible you just needed to wait for your DNS changes to propagate.
2. Cloudflare provide [very fast](http://www.solvedns.com/dns-comparison/2013/01) free domain name resolution. It's worth sticking with them unless they don't offer a DNS feature you need.

Comment: OK, thanks. We were using the default Go Daddy DNS servers, but you recommend Cloudflare over Go Daddy, I presume? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. Even if you don't turn on Cloudflare's CDN and protection services (which are also excellent), their DNS hosting is fantastic.

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2013/03/03/cloudflare-is-down-due-to-dns-outage-taking-down-785000-websites-including-4chan-wikileaks-metallica-com/  and read the comments.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos No service has 100% uptime. e.g. http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2012/09/godaddy-moves-to-verisign/ Cloudflare downtime is rare and their team offers excellent incident reports on their [blog](http://blog.cloudflare.com/).

Comment: @Nick no kidding but 1 hour down is a lot of time. And it happened 3 times in one year. I have nothing against the company and their free services are great. But they are still fairly new on the DNS scene (maybe 4 years). Even their CEO Mr Prince thought it was unexceptional downtime. Free service is that, you get what you pay for. I just wanted to put it out there so people can make their own decisions.